# A great idea from another stack exchange site

Tags: discussion

[This stack exchange community has 
 great idea](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5029/to-celebrate-mi-yodeyas-10th-birthday-lets-divide-and-conquer-the-entire-mish)

Read a passage of the Bible, reflect on it, consult a commentary if necessary, **and find a discussion on this site that relates to it**.

I'm not a member of this community, but if there's someone around here who wants to take charge of such a project, I would be happy to contribute a chapter or two! (How many people or chapters per person would we need to complete such a project?)

Comment: The Christian Bible is **huge**.

Comment: Honestly, I'm not clear on what the point is either on that site or on this one.

Comment: @Kyralessa I can't speak to this site, but I can explain what we're doing on Mi Yodeya. First, organized learning programs (studying each book of the Hebrew bible, or an entire tractate of talmud, or all of the mishna (part of the talmud), etc) are traditional in Judaism & end with a celebration. Second, we have a teaching that at the age of 5 one begins to learn torah, at 10 mishna, at 15 g'mara, and so on. Against that backdrop, the site will be having its tenth birthday at the end of this year, so we're following that learning program (i.e. learn mishna) and distributing it so we do it all.

Comment: Maybe I am too much of a computer scientist, but I can't help but think that indexing the questions/answers with verses mentioned in them can't be THAT hard. There are only about 15000 questions on here, and even if the average were 2 answers, that only makes 30000 answers. The hardest part would be identifying what verses are mentioned. I know this defeats the study together part, though ;-)

Comment: I don't have time to do it, but if anyone is interested in trying, here is a [python package to identify bible references](https://pypi.org/project/pythonbible/), and here you can find [data dumps of Stack Exchange sites](https://archive.org/details/stackexchange). I estimate maybe two to four hours of coding and then a few hours at most for actually executing the code.

Comment: @kutschkem Now *that* software project is officially on my "someday/maybe" dream list. :-)    And thank you for the software suggestions! I might be using those for another project any week now!

Answer (score 2):

I was thinking a while ago that we should start a Catechism, but maybe a Concordance would a a better (and more Ecumenical) way of doing things.  This is a great idea, we might want to start with a Google Docs sheet and seed a few answers before opening it up to the whole community (or just expecting people to participate)  If it gets going, we mods can tag it to the right menu on the main site and it can be a thing.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't really understand what your proposal is.

Comment: @k-HB, an index of Answers with Biblical references for different topics

Comment: What do you want to do wiht Google Docs and what do you want to tag where? I have seen the project on judaism.SE. What exactly do you want?

Comment: A different idea fwiw is a study group -- e.g. people (in the group) agree on a text to study, read it and then ask and real questions about it they may have. Often (i.e. on more than one site I've seen that) a group like that will book, e.g. one chapter per week. And they can answer the answer the questions because they've read the same book.

Comment: Theoretically, I understand stanch of your  question, but as times foreseen as something about Catholicism that is different

Comment: Would this be only for topics that *all* denominations agree on?
Or will there be a long list of conflicting answers for each topic?
(I'm not trying to shoot down the idea; I'm trying to understand how you see it working.)

Comment: @ray, yeah, I don't know whether it's better to categorize by denomination and the break down by topic of vice versa. I think I was drawing my inspiration from a site that showed how to write thousands of basic programming algorithms in 30 different languages.  Maybe the breakdown would be how we all achieve certain ends or explain certain doctrines.